# Passport.authenticate not calling in Node/MongoDB application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to set up local user auth in a Node/MongoDB application.

This is the file in question. I cannot get `passport.authenticate('local')` to fire. I have tried different variations using `next()` and invoking the passport.authenticate as a separate callback, but it still does not register.

I am also using `https` and have am using `bodyparser` appropriately

```
...

router.post('/join', function(req, res, next) {
  const {email, password} = req.body;

  User.register(new User({
    username:email,
    email: email
  }),password,function(err,account){
    if (err){
      console.log('err',err);
    }
    console.log('here') // works

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err,user,info){
      console.log('am i here'); // does not work
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});
```

For reference, here are my other setup files.

```
server.js
...

app.use(session({
  secret: 'ama-app',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', routes);
var User = require('./models/User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Below I have the file setup for the User Schema

```
models/User.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username:String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by using this code from the [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#custom-callback).

```
router.post('/join', function(req, res, next) {
  const {email, password} = req.body;

  User.register(new User({
    username:email,
    email: email
  }),password,function(err,account){
    if (err){
      console.log('err',err);
    }
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        // redirects successfully
        return res.redirect('/');
      }

    })(req, res, next);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's important to remember that at the end of the day, Express is a middleware application. Where you're using passport in your POST endpoint doesn't really make sense to me. Usually I would use Passport as middleware to protect an endpoint, but not directly in the endpoint I'm writing.

From what I can tell, you're trying to login a new user immediately when they register. [According to the docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/), the most idiomatic way to do this is using `req.login()`.

Here's something like what I'd expect you to be doing:

```
router.post('/join', function(req, res, next) {
  const {email, password} = req.body;

  User.register(new User({
    username:email,
    email: email
  }),password,function(err,account){
    if (err){
      console.log('err',err);
      // IMPORTANT: need to return here
      return next(err);
    }

    req.login(account, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});
```